# Android Pagination BoundaryCallback with Placeholders not working correctly?

Tags: android, pagination

I have started migration from RecycledViewAdapter to PagedListAdapter and to accomplish this I'm using RxPagedListBuilder with ItemKeyedDataSource, BoundaryCallback and Placeholders enabled.

I am referring to Network Data with Database as Cache design which suggests that BoundaryCallback will be called when my DataSource (loads from the local database) runs out of data.

As it turns out, BoundaryCallback#onItemAtEndLoaded never gets called and I was quite puzzled.

My ItemKeyedDataSource returns my first loaded page (15 items) from the database + the totalCount of all available items fetch-able from the network (246) using callback(data, totalCount) on loadInitial()

When I scroll down my list, first 15 items appear as expected, but then I see a bunch of placeholders and no BoundaryCallback calls are made.

I have tried to analyze the code that should make a call to BoundaryCallback#onItemAtEndLoaded and the condition is as follows (PagedList):

```
 private void tryDispatchBoundaryCallbacks(boolean post) {
    ...

    final boolean dispatchEnd = mBoundaryCallbackEndDeferred
            && mHighestIndexAccessed >= size() - 1 - mConfig.prefetchDistance;

    if (!dispatchBegin && !dispatchEnd) {
        return;
    }

    if (dispatchEnd) {
        mBoundaryCallbackEndDeferred = false;
    }
    if (post) {
        mMainThreadExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dispatchBoundaryCallbacks(dispatchBegin, dispatchEnd);
            }
        });
    } else {
        dispatchBoundaryCallbacks(dispatchBegin, dispatchEnd);
    }
}
```

You can see that the mHighestIndexAccessed has to be greater than size() - 1 - mConfig.PrefetchDistance; however, size() evaluates as follows:

```
mLeadingNullCount + mStorageCount + mTrailingNullCount
```

Simply put, it adds placeholders into the calculation (returns 246). So in case if 16th item is being accessed, this evaluates to 15 > 246 - 1 - 15 => 15 > 230. In other words, the BoundaryCallback will never invoke it's method unless I scroll all the way to the bottom (scrolling through all placeholders).

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, Adam. Did you find the solution for this behaviour? Unfortunately, i'm having the same problem and I can't find the solution to this problem.

Comment: @VictorFerrucy Unfortunately there seems to be no solution. I also have an open git issue about this which received no comments: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/662 the implementation in place does not make sense to me I hope someone can follow up.